etcd is out of space, getting NOSPACE alarm
We have two node patroni postgres databases on preprod environment. Today I tried to do patronictl edit-config and saw etcd was out of space. I looked at /var/lib/etcd/member directory and it was around 2GB. Because of this I can't edit postgresql.conf file but also manage patroni cluster.
I tried etcdctl compact and defrag commands but they did nothing. Etcd database size remained the same. I'd like to decrease size of etcd with correct methods so I'd really appreciate your help.
